# Pipelined region scheduling strategy in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, scheduler, flink-streaming

I have been trying to understand the pipelined region scheduling in Flink. I have read [this](https://flink.apache.org/2020/12/15/pipelined-region-sheduling.html) blog from Flink on this topic. The blog says the following about how to find pipelined regions.

> A pipelined region is a subset of subtasks in the ExecutionGraph
> connected by pipelined data exchanges. Subtasks from different
> pipelined regions are connected only by blocking data exchanges.

The blog also has an example of a two-phase join between tables where the join operator has a blocking and a pipelined input.

I have extended the join example in the blog to create the following interesting example.

[image]

In this workflow, there is only one blocking link (shown in red). If we remove that blocking link, the rest of the workflow still remains connected using the pipelined links.

My questions are:

1. How many pipelined regions are there in this workflow? Following the blog, I think there is only one pipelined region.
2. How does Flink execute this workflow? If there is just one pipelined region, does Flink execute the whole workflow at the same time? If that happens, does the join operator receive input from both `Order` and `Customer` tables at the same time?